# Getting a TypeError #1123: Filter operator not supported on type, MainTimeline/enterFrameHandler ()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I'm trying to take an older tutorial for a star field from `AS2` and port it over to `AS3`. I am no longer getting any compiler errors, but I am getting a `TypeError`.

Here is the code:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

var stars = 100;
var maxSpeed = 16;
var minSpeed = 2;

for( var i = 0; i<stars; i++)
{
    var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    addChild(mc);
    mc.name = "star","star"+i,i;
    mc.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
    mc.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    mc.speed = Math.random() * (maxSpeed-minSpeed)+minSpeed
    var size = Math.random() * 2+(0.6*(Math.random() * 4));
    mc.width = size;
    mc.height = size;
}

function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var target:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target);
    for (var j = 0; j<stars;j++)
    {
        var mc = this.("star"+j);
        if (mc.y>0)
        { 
            mc.y -= mc.speed;
        }
        else
        {
            mc.y = stage.stageHeight;
            mc.speed = Math.random() * (maxSpeed-minSpeed)+minSpeed;
            mc.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;

        }
    }
};
```

The `TypeError` I am getting is this:

> TypeError: Error #1123: Filter operator not supported on type
>   SpaceBoost_loadscreen_star_fla.MainTimeline.  at
>   SpaceBoost_loadscreen_star_fla::MainTimeline/enterFrameHandler()

I am very new to coding in Actionscript, and am just learning as I go. 
Also, any helpful suggestions on how to clean it up are also welcome!

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Two issues I see after a quick glance:

**Issue 1:**

In your first for loop, this line: `mc.name = "star","star"+i,i;`

The name for each item will end up being the same ("star"), because after the comma it's just going to be a string literal command (assuming this isn't throwing an error as well).

Correct by changing this to:

```
mc.name = "star" + i;
```

**Issue 2**:

What is throwing the current error,   `var mc = this.("star"+j);`
In AS3, `object.(expression)` is E4X filtering.   To access an object via instance name, do the following instead:

```
var mc = getChildByName("star" + j);
```

I'm pretty rusty on this, so let me know if doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I changed these parts, but now i am getting a new error:                                                                           TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
at SpaceBoost_loadscreen3_star_fla::MainTimeline/enterFrameHandler()            So there is definitely an issue with how i handle the event enterframeHandler

Comment: I made a little update in the Issue2 section suggested code.  It would be helpful if you debugged and showed the actual line that is throwing the error.

Comment: That's the issue, my compiler isn't showing that there are any issues. But the stars are not populating, and i am getting the type error in the output section. Based off of what i have looked up it seems to be a runtime error (#1006) and it seems to not be recognizing my EventListener as a function. Maybe the API for the first line isn't handled correctly? the other issue could be i am not calling the objects correctly, but everything seems to be spelled right....hmmm

Comment: What version of flashPro are you using?   Do you have strict compiling and warning turned on in the actionscript settings?   Are you using the debug menu when testing?